# Can I see the log of which files were opened on my system for the past one hour in windows 7?

Tags: windows, windows-7

Someone has logged in as admin into my system and i want to see which files did he open?
Does windows 7 has some default logger?
Event logger is just showing me the logged in info and services and errors.
I want to see the file names which were opened.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

http://www.groovypost.com/howto/microsoft/enable-last-access-time-stamp-to-files-folder-windows-7/

Hopes it work for you.

Comment: Exactly the thing i wanted.. Thanks a ton

Answer (score 2):

Here is the default setup without recent documents on the start menu,

no recent documents in Windows 7

1) Right click on the Windows taskbar and go to Properties.

Under Start Menu click Customize as shown below.

customize start menu

2) Find out ‘Recent Items’ and enable it. Also you can control the number of recent items to show in the list from start menu.

enable recent items in Windows 7

3) Press OK to show recent documents on the start menu.

Recent items on Windows 7 start menu